# How to find out the pattern or structure of the ACF plot only through the equation of an AR(1) process?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I recently started studying about time series analysis and forecasting and stuck on a problem statement as follows:
I have been only given the equation of one $MR(1)$ and $AR(1)$ processes i.e.
$Z_{t} = 0.5a_{t - 1} + a_{t}$ and the other one $Z_{t} = 0.8z_{t - 1} + a_{t}$ and asked to determine the pattern of the $ACF$ plots generated for the both the processes.

The only thing which I am able to get from the equation is that as $|\phi| < 1$ means the given time series data for which $AR(1)$ equation is generated is stationary. But how to find out the information for the pattern or structure of $ACF$ plots from the equations given.

Could you also generalize the steps for any type of $AR(1)$ and $MR(1)$ process equation?

Comment: Hi:You need to derive the expression for the acf for an AR(1). It ends up being $\gamma(n) = \phi^n$ where $\phi$ is the AR(1) parameter. Then, from that expression, the plot is straightforward.

Comment: Hi, I would really appreciate it if you can expand on the answer given. Thanks

Comment: @mlofton So as we know $\gamma(n) = \phi^{n}\; where\; n >= 0$ so I just need to calculate for $n$ lags and when $n = 0 \; \gamma(n) = 1$.

Comment: hi yes, you can just plot $\phi^n$ for different values of $n$ and that will give you the acf plot. And yes, by definition, the autocorrelation at lag 0 is equal to 1. But, , may I also suggest that you read some intro book on time series such as Chatfield's or Hyndman's. This way, you get a feel for time-series principles and concepts in general. Box- Jenkins-Reinsel is a whole book devoted to ARIMA modelling but I don't suggest it as an introductory book. It would be good as a second book.

Comment: @mlofton Thanks for the explanation and I will surely look at the book you suggested. Thanks